# C#. Удалить из файла всё что не связано с введённым ID

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
У меня есть такой файл:

```
"users"
{
  "76561198405997878"
  {
    "AccountName"       "maks_22_pro"
    "PersonaName"       "ZTESLA.RU"
    "RememberPassword"      "0"
    "mostrecent"        "1"
    "Timestamp"     "1572455393"
  }
}
{
  "76561198404997878"
  {
    "AccountName"       "maks_422_pro"
    "PersonaName"       "ZTESLA.RU4"
    "RememberPassword"      "0"
    "mostrecent"        "1"
    "Timestamp"     "1572455393"
  }
}
```

И вот к примеру я ввожу свой ID ("76561198405997878") и всё что с этим ID не связано должно удалиться из файла.
То есть на выходе я должен получить такой файл:

```
{
  "76561198405997878"
  {
    "AccountName"       "maks_22_pro"
    "PersonaName"       "ZTESLA.RU"
    "RememberPassword"      "0"
    "mostrecent"        "1"
    "Timestamp"     "1572455393"
  }
}
```

Это был первый ID, а не нужный был ниже. Он был удалён.
как такое реализовать?

Comment: Это очень похоже на JSON, но всё же не он. Вы _точно_ скопировали данные, ничего не изменили? / С помощью какой библиотеки создаются эти данные? Вероятно, она же умеет и парсить их. / Если вы получаете эти данные откуда-то извне, уточните там формат. Могут ли его изменить на стандартный JSON? Или если это вы так записываете данные, то измените способ записи.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov файл формата vdf. Это не json, ничего не изменял, скопировал так же. Это связано с Steam Api, но нет возможности его использовать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Вспомнил - Steamworks.net библиотека

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov нет возможности парсить ею, и записать по другому. Нужно как то руками убрать ненужные ID. Сложно оч, решил суда вопрос задать, но вот тоже никто не отвечает

Comment: В плане нет возможности? Стим может спокойно отдавать данные в JSON формате, что вам мешает использовать этот формат?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня нет стима и почему то я не могу установить его в проект в Visual Studio.

Comment: у стима есть API, используйте его

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
        /// Метод парсит файл с пользователями
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pathToFile">путь к файлу с данными</param>
        /// <param name="idToRemove">ид который надо удалить</param>
        private void UserParser(string @pathToFile,string idToRemove)
        {



            string pathToSaveUpdatedFile = "Updated.txt"; // сохраняет в файл в рядом с программой
            int indexRemoveFrom=-1;

           string[] fileOrignData = File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile);


            for (int i = 0; i < fileOrignData.Length; i++)
            {
                if (fileOrignData[i].Contains(idToRemove))
                {
                    indexRemoveFrom = i - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }


            if (indexRemoveFrom == -1)
            {
                return;
            }
            string[] fileUpdatedData = new string[fileOrignData.Length - 10];

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < fileUpdatedData.Length; i++, j++)
            {
                if (indexRemoveFrom == i)
                {
                    j = j + 9;
                }
                else
                {
                    fileUpdatedData[i] = fileOrignData[j];
                }
            }

            File.WriteAllLines(pathToSaveUpdatedFile, fileUpdatedData);

        }
```